# General help/advice with buttons and popups

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jpopupmenu

Hi and thanks in advance!

I've been working on a game project and no I'm looking into making a basic GUI. To put it short this is what I'm trying to achieve:

The primary component is a J(Scroll)panel that houses moving in-game objects. I want the players to be able to hover the mouse over an object and get some kind of information popup that is tied to the location of the object hovered over. Secondly I want the user to be able to click on an object with the left mouse button in order to "select" the object and also to be able click with the right mouse button to open a popup menu next to the object.

Comment: So what is the query here? You want to know how to handle left and right click events in swing? Or you are open to any technology stack and want to know the best approach possible?

Comment: I am an amateur when it comes to GUI's So any I'd like to know where to start and What components should I look into when building this.. Just general advice how to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a mouse listener to your panel. Like this:

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
    System.out.println(me); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: ok.. but how do I connect the mouse click with the component that was clicked? the only way that I know how to do involves polygons and the method contains(); and I don't think that is the way to go ;D

Comment: what type of objects are the components that you want to assign the mouselistener to?

Comment: well if you mean the object that i want to click on it's really nothing yet.. It's a class that I built, resembling a vessel but that's about it not much graphics on it yet

Comment: does your class include an image? if you don't want to deal with poligons you able to check frame of image for clicks and if click on frame happens check does this click point to alpha channel

Comment: So I should add a listener to my image? that I can grasp but you lost me at alpha channel..

Comment: I mean you should add a listener to panel, in this listener every component should be checked for intersection between coordinates of mouse click and a frame of component image. If your images have an alpha channel(or any mark of empty place, so frame of image is lager than component), listener also should check if click points exacltly on colored part, not alpha-channel.

Comment: Soo.. I add a listener to the panel, make it check if the click intersect an image and make sure it isn't clicked on a transparent section of the image. I think I got that but how do I exactly check if it intersects with the image?

Comment: Do you know a coordinates and widht/height of your images? If so, you might create a list of components and add a check for every image in this list for intersection with mouse click coordinate.